# How to change GET to POST?

Tags: javascript, html

**How do I change a `GET` method to a `POST` method?**

I have this code that I trial and error-ed till I got it working, but due to my limitations on the language I'm struggling to understand how I can proceed further.

```
document.querySelectorAll("nav ul li a#pg").forEach(function(a){
    a.addEventListener("click", function(){

        // Putting together a URL
        var page = this.getAttribute("href").substring(1);
        var url = "pages/" + page + ".html";

        // Location to load content
        var loadCon = document.getElementById("content");

        // XMLHttpRequest code
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            loadCon.innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };

        xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xhttp.send();
    });
});
```

What I do know, is that I'm required to add a
`xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");`
between `.open` and `.send`.
And parameters for `.send`.

The part that I'm struggling with is actually the parameters that I'm required to set.

The .html file is a basic html file without a form in it, what I'm trying to achieve is to find a way to use `POST` method to dynamically replace content, without any php involved.

Above all, I really appreciate for the help anyone provides and thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't think you can do this without a server.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little new to this myself, but this is how I understand it (could be totally off though so my bad):

first, you would need to identify what you will be sending in your post:
var params = { "value": 1, "description": "stuff"};

so in your:
xhttp.open("GET", url, true); you would change your "GET" with "POST" so: xhttp.open("POST", url, true);

then in your:
xhttp.send(); you would add your params xhttp.send(params);

hope that helps!

Comment: Hi newToThis, thanks for answering. I will try it out and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I remember getting confused by this back in the day. First try getting plain HTML forms working, then move up to AJAX.

From the top:

HTML files are just plain old text files that can't change anything by themselves. Your HTTP server (of which PHP is a part of) does all the actual processing.

If you're loading your HTML page from a file:// URL, then you're not using an HTTP server at all - your browser is just grabbing it from your computer's filesystem and displaying whatever is in the file.

If you're loading your HTML page from an http:// URL, then your web browser is

1. Asking your OS to open a TCP connection (basically a bidirectional TTY chat channel) to the IP address of your server on port 80 or 443
2. Sending an [HTTP request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST#Example) by literally "typing in" the request and then following it by two newlines.
3. Waiting for your HTTP server to process the request and then send back an [HTTP response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Session) that has the new HTML as part of it.

From your HTTP server's perspective, a request comes in, it does stuff with the request and edits the HTML page (or whatever data it generates the HTML page from) using PHP, and then sends back the new HTML. So you need to use PHP for that. :)

Comment: Hi Dylan, thanks for the process break down, it's really clear. From my understanding php is a server side language and because it is a cross browser platform people use it to produce dynamic pages.